# Reverse Nested Relationship Serialization in django rest framework

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am working on a deals/coupon selling website. I have following models, (excluding extra details).

```
    class Order(models.Model):

        email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, null=False)
        phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False)
        shipping_address = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
        coupon_code = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)
        gross_total = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

        class Meta:
            db_table = 'order'


    class OrderDetail(models.Model):
        order = models.ForeignKey(Order,related_name='order_details')
        package = models.ForeignKey(Package)
        quantity = models.IntegerField(null=False)
        unit_price = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

        class Meta:
            db_table = 'order_detail'




    class Coupon(models.Model):
        order_detail = models.ForeignKey(OrderDetail,related_name='coupons')
        code = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, unique=True)
        maximum_usage_count = models.IntegerField(null=False)
        used_count =  models.IntegerField(default=0)
        valid_from = models.DateTimeField(null=False)
        valid_to = models.DateTimeField(null=False)

        class Meta:
            db_table = 'coupon'
```

My serializers for these are,

```
    class CouponSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Coupon
            fields = ['id', 'code', 'maximum_usage_count', 'used_count', 'valid_from', 'valid_to', 'created_at',
                      'updated_at', 'is_active']


    class OrderDetailSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        coupons = CouponSerializer(read_only=True)

        class Meta:
            model = OrderDetail
            fields = ['id', 'package', 'quantity', 'unit_price', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'is_active']


    class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        order_details = OrderDetailSerializer(read_only=True,many=True)

        class Meta:
            model = Order
            fields = ['id','email', 'phone_number', 'shipping_address', 'coupon_code', 'gross_total','order_details']
```

In my listapiview, for fetching all orders, I have specified the order serializer. The api is working fine but is not able to serialize the reverse relation ship models. I am getting following response.

```
{
            "id": 31,
            "email": "ff@b.com",
            "first_name": "ff",
            "last_name": "ff",
            "phone_number": "ff",
            "shipping_address": "",
            "coupon_code": "",
            "gross_total": 1.0,
            "payment_method": "ONLINE",
            "order_status": "PLACED",
            "created_at": "2016-10-01T17:26:00.432000",
            "updated_at": "2016-10-01T17:48:50.797000",
            "is_active": true,
            "order_details": [
                {
                    "coupons": {}
                },
                {
                    "coupons": {}
                },
                {
                    "coupons": {}
                }
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace the inherited class with `serializers.ModelSerializer` in `CouponSerializer` and `OrderDetailSerializer` instead of just `serializer.Serializer` - just like you did in `OrderSerializer`.

After that you'll get some errors because your models (Coupon and OrderDetail) don't declare any of `created_at`, `updated_at` nor `is_active` fields. So you should add those fields to your models or remove them from the list in `Meta` in both serializer classes. But after that it works as expected.